# iPad 2, iPhone 4s and iMessage

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, messages

I have an iPad2 and an iPhone 4s. My daughter has an iPhone 4, my son has an iPod 4th generation, and my husband has an iPhone4s. We all share the same iTunes account but all have our own emails.

I sent an iMessage to my dad on my iphone4s and it went to my son and daughter at school, my husband at work and my iPad at home. How do I unsync so that it does not go to all devices?

I want to be able to message from my phone without sending it to everyone in my family, as well as send from my iPad and not have it go to all other devices. This started when I got a new iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Change the email address in the Settings app under Messages:

[image]
[image]